# how to pass multiple requestIDs to cancelDeploy() in ant migration tool

Tags: deployment, ant, ant-script

I have multiple deployments queued/stuck in one org that i want to cancel. I tried using ant migration tool's cancelDeployment method but it only allows one Id at a time, as per the document.

"requestId  : Required. Specifies the ID of an in-progress or queued deployment to cancel." here in the link to [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_cancel.htm)

is there anyway i can add multiple ids? thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up using selenium IDE and automate the manual steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is No and you can have one requestId at a time, You would need to manually click cancel next to the deployment.

You can initiate multiple deployments however only one deployment can run at a time. Review details of [Cancel an in progress deployment or validation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000357635&type=1) and [Monitor Deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.deploy_monitoring.htm&type=5).

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer my question.